# Android Studio 'invalid method id' when debuging

Tags: android-studio

When I try to debug an app and app execution stops on my breakpoint I can not see the current line or values. Debug window says `Invalid method id`. Tried cleaning, rebuilding and invalidate cache/restart.

Comment: I have the same error and it happens when breakpoints are in default method implementations of an interface. Is it the same in your case?

Comment: Yes. And I use multiple such interfaces with default methods

Comment: Ok, so it looks like a bug and we need to report it.

Comment: I did it. Feel free to join or follow: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190941827

Comment: Same thing for me, default methods on interfaces, with latest Android Studio + build tools + Gradle. Upvoted the issue tracker, although it seems to be closed as "not reproducible".